# How do I change user presence status in RingCentral programmatically using C#?

Tags: c#, ringcentral, user-presence

I have created as program in C# that is designed to display the users status and availability from RingCentral.

This works brilliantly and I can sort the users by availability, name, etc.

I need to add the functionality to change the status of the user to "Offline".  When the users shift ends they would be set to receive calls when they have gone home, we need to stop that.

The problem I have is that the RingCentral SDK I am using is saying it needs a parameter which should be of type PresenceInfoResource.  here is the path I am using:

```
rc.Restapi().Account().Extension().Presence().Put();
```

I have tried various different types but I cannot seem to get, create or cast to a type of PresenceInfoResource.

Does anyone know what it is looking for, how to change the status in c# or where I am going wrong?

I have looked in the RingCentral documentation on line, but can't find anything, only a link to the update presence page which has nothing about `PresenceInfoResource`:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Presence/updateUserPresenceStatus

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer to this from another site:

```
    var parameters = new PresenceInfoResource();
    parameters.userStatus = "Busy";
    parameters.dndStatus = "TakeAllCalls";
    var resp = await rc.Restapi().Account().Extension().Presence().Put(parameters);   
    Console.WriteLine("User presence status: " + resp.userStatus);
    Console.WriteLine("User DND status: " + resp.dndStatus);
```